# Report engine suitable for iOS?

Tags: ios4, reporting, template-engine

I need to build a dozens of report (invoices & stuff) and wonder if exist any report engine that let me make band reports.

I'm building a custom-one based on UIView, but is quickly becoming problematic. For example, I think on use a TableView for the invoice detail, but then is necessary to grow it to the total of records, so all data is show at once. And that is only a problem.

Then is the problem of pages, breaks, etc.

So I think in use UIPrintFormatter, but is only for AirPrint (I need to show previews, print to pdf, etc)

Answer (score 0):

There [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) cloud service might be able to help.  It is only for the reporting side (not data entry).  You upload templates via the web site, then your app can send data to merge with the templates and stream the document back or email it off etc.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [i-net Clear-Reports together with iOS](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/clear-reports/editions/mobile/ios).